# Removing the [recommendations] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [recommendations](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag on [Proof Assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/).

Should this be deleted, as it encourages opinion-based answers?

Comment: This is a meta-tag, which should be avoided, but several sites find a variation of this one to be of some use. If these site end up being migration partners, then this tag will be useful to facilitate migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this tag a handful of times for questions that are asking about *software that satisfies some property* such as [being an automated theorem prover for a constructive logic](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/347/are-there-automated-theorem-provers-for-constructive-logics-what-strategy-do-th). It seems to also be used for questions [like this one](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/237/is-there-an-official-recommendation-for-editors-to-input-lean-unicode-characters) about the usage of a specific proof assistant.

I think this tag should be split into [software-request](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-request), by analogy with [reference-request](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) which seems to be well-established on multiple sites, and maybe restrict the scope of [recommendation](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) to idiomatic usage of a specific prover.

Comment: @GuyCoder ... Did you mean to comment on a different post? This one is about  the tag [tag:recommendations].

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You're saying if I want to split the tags in a way that seems reasonable, just do it and trust the system to require consensus when consensus is required (such as adding tag synonyms). Okay.

Comment: Which sites use "software-request"? I know some that use "software-recommendations".

Comment: I suppose none of them except us. I somewhat support a new tag [:software-recommendation] and merging [:software-request] into it or deleting it outright. The only potential problem with the `-recommendation` language is that not every question that asks for specific software is asking for software with a specific *good* trait.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the equivalent of:

- Matter Modeling's [software-recommendations tag which currently has about 100 out of the site's 2000 questions](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) or
- the [recommendations tag  which currently has about 40 out of the site's 700 questions](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) on Drones.SE.

I think we should also keep the tag here, just like we do on those sites and others.

Comment: Ok, thanks. After this answer, I agree and am going to edit the description for the tag :)